# Как посмотреть трафик Android-устройства?

Tags: android, wifi

Смартфон на Android стал есть батарею. При отключении Wi-fi проблема исчезает. Программы типа Viber остановил, но всё равно при включенном Wi-fi батарея высаживается за день.

Можно ли с компа, подключенного к тому же Wi-fi роутеру посмотреть ip-адреса, на которые лезет смартфон?

Comment: можно посмотреть логи роутера если совсем нужно, но я думаю что у вас проблема в телефоне, а вернее в оптимизации, вам нужно отключить фоновые соединения, и запретить работу в фоне, и может у вас там поселился вирус, но решить проблему просмотром логов на роутере вы врядли сможете

Comment: в андроиде есть кнопка использования батареии приложениями